# How to call another page, run javascript to collect cityname and postal code and return to previous page with cityname and postcode as parameter

Tags: javascript

On our website we need to find out which city and or postal code the visitor are calling from. To do this we have access to maxmind.com and there geoip.

In this javasript i build a parameter string whith cityname, postal code and region. You can call it on https://leasebil.nu/test/geo1.html

```
    <script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js"></script>
    <script>
       var fillInPage = (function () {
           var updateCityText = function (geoipResponse) {

           var link = "/shelter?lat=" + geoipResponse.location.latitude;
           link += "&lon=" +geoipResponse.location.longitude;

           /* It's possible that we won't have any names for this city */
           var cityName = geoipResponse.city.names.en || 'your city';
           var postcode = geoipResponse.postal.code || 'your posnumber';

        /*
           most_specific_subdivision returns the smallest available
           subdivision (region) as defined in ISO 3166-2.
        */
           var regionName = geoipResponse.most_specific_subdivision.names.en;

           var cityHTML = "https://leasebil.nu/default.asp?cn=" + cityName + "&pc=" + postcode + "&rn=" + regionName;

           $("#city").html(cityHTML);
       };

       var onSuccess = function (geoipResponse) {
           updateCityText(geoipResponse);
       };

    /* If we get an error we will */
       var onError = function (error) {
           return;
       };

       return function () {
           geoip2.city( onSuccess, onError );
       };
   }());

   fillInPage();

    </script>
```

How do i code a redirect in this script that redirect to the caling website = variable CityHTML?

Comment: are you asking about simple redirect? `window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com"`

Comment: Yes and no - my skills are bad in java so i need help to place the redirect in the code. I have tried this   after  fillInPage();
   window.location = 'https://leasebil.nu/default.asp?' + cityHTML; but nothing happens - perhaps the help i need are simple! Thanks in advance

Comment: no you can't do it after fillInPage. do it after `$("#city").html(cityHTML)`

Comment: SOLVED - Thank you Eduard Jacko - fantastic fast help - thank you.